# Dúvida em uma questão de linguagem C

Tags: c

> Escreva uma função que receba um vetor de 10 números inteiros e retorne a
>   quantidade de números distintos que compõem o vetor.

Por exemplo, se o vetor dado for `v = {3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 5, 2}`, a função deve retornar o número 5.
E quando por exemplo eu digito do 1 ao 10, ele me volta 1, se eu digito 5 números 1 e 5 números 2, ele me volta 5.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define TAM 10

int difNumbers(int array[], int count) {
    int uniqValue[count];
    int n = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        unsigned char foundUnique = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < count; x++) {
            if(uniqValue[x] == array[i]) {
                foundUnique = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(foundUnique) {
            uniqValue[n] = array[i];
            n++;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

int main()  {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int vector[TAM], i;

    for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
        printf("[%d]:", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
    }
    printf("%d", difNumbers(vector, TAM));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema começa no teste feito no `if`, aqui:

```
if(foundUnique) {
```

Devia na verdade ser o oposto, com o operator `not`:

```
if(!foundUnique) {
// ^--
```

Porque o seu `foundUnique` na verdade indica se o elemento existe no novo array de únicos, e apenas quer adicionar se ainda não existir. Outro pormenor relevante é que está a percorrer mais elementos que os que devia quando tenta verificar se o elemento existe no novo array de únicos:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
//                   ^---
```

O `count` vale `10` que é o valor enviado no `main` mas inicialmente você não tem 10 elementos no array, e como nem foram inicializados acaba por apanhar lixo da memoria, e pode acertar num valor dos que já digitou. Correto é percorrer apenas sobre a quantidade já inserida, com `n`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
//                 ^---
```

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone com as duas alterações mencionadas acima](https://ideone.com/uQ2fTX)